# Traversing Table guava

Tags: hashmap, guava

I have used table guava for my 3D implementation of hash, I just wanted to know like how to iterate that and fetch the values. I have the below in my table now .. I just have to traverse this and print the value of row, column,  value

```
  A1000|B100|8
  A104|B10|6
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for (Table.Cell<String, String, Integer> cell : table.cellSet()) {
    System.out.println(cell.getRowKey 
                       + "|"
                       + cell.getColumnKey() 
                       + "|" 
                       + cell.getValue());
}
```

[The javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/index.html) would have told you, as well as the linked [user guide article](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table).